# Unable to connect to sql server database from azure HDinsights spark cluster using sqoop

Tags: azure, hive, sqoop, azure-hdinsight

Getting firewall errors, don't know y because all ports were open and m able to connect it from other clients as well. Even not able to ping my linux cluster from other machine.

[image: Exception]

Comment: please submit any error messages as text, *not* as screenshot. if you can't even ping your target, it seems to be a network issue, not a coding issue, which is completely off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot shows

```
... Login failed for user ''
```

Did you specify the credentails (Arguments: --username and --password)